# How to put the sum inside the manipulate

Tags: manipulate

```
Manipulate[
  a = 0;
  b = 10;
  dx = (b - a)/n;
  f[x_] = 2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2;

  Show[
    DiscretePlot[
      2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2,{x, 0, b, dx},
      ExtentSize -> Left,
      PlotRange->{{a, 10.5},{0, 2600}},
      ColorFunction -> (Green &),
      ExtentElementFunction -> 
        ({EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle @@ Transpose @ #} &)
    ],
    Plot[
      2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2, {x, a,b }, 
      PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
    ],
    Sum[dx*f[a + i*dx],{i, 1, n},{n, 5, 50}], {n, 5, 50}
]
```

Comment: @marcoB No, given the title, OP is looking to add the numerical value to the plot, he's not asking about the Riemann sum itself.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post. If you want to disassociate this post from your account, please [follow this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26853/241919) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you haven't got this of the form `Manipulate[expr,{x,xmin,xmax}]`. Using `Column` is one way you can group everything and then adjust the layout with e.g. `Alignment` option. `Grid` and `Row` are other options you could consider.

```
Manipulate[a = 0; b = 10; dx = (b - a)/n;
 Column[{Show[
    DiscretePlot[2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2, {x, 0, b, dx}, 
     ExtentSize -> Left, PlotRange -> {{a, 10.5}, {0, 2600}}, 
     ImageSize -> 400, ColorFunction -> (Green &), 
     ExtentElementFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], 
         Rectangle @@ Transpose@#} &)], 
    Plot[2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2, {x, a, b}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]], 
   N@Sum[dx*f[a + i*dx], {i, 1, n}, {n, 5, 50}]}], {n, 5, 50, 1}, 
 Initialization :> {f[x_] = 2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2}]
```

[image]

From here you can position things and set font styles and sizes etc

Answer (score 6):

Your sum is all wrong, you aren't getting the right answer or even close.  You can check by taking the actual integral.

Anyway, you can use `Inset` to put any text inside your graphic, like this

```
Manipulate[a = 0; b = 10; dx = (b - a)/n;
 xi[i_] := Which[Method == "Upper", a + (i + 1)*dx,
   Method == "Lower", a + i*dx,
   Method == "Middle", a + dx/2 + dx i];
 rectangles = 
  Table[{Opacity[0.3], Green, EdgeForm[Gray], 
    Rectangle[{a + i*dx, 0}, {a + (i + 1)*dx, f[xi[i]]}]}, {i, 0, 
    n - 1, 1}];
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}],
  Graphics@rectangles, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \
\(i\)]\)f(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(i\)]\))dx = " <> 
      ToString[N@Sum[dx*f[xi[i]], {i, 0, n - 1}]], Scaled[{.3, .8}]], 
    Inset["\[Integral]f(x)\[DifferentialD]x = " <> 
      ToString[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]], Scaled[{.3, .6}]]}], {{n,5},
   5, 50, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, {{Method, "Upper"}, {"Upper", "Lower", 
   "Middle"}, ControlType -> Setter}, 
    Initialization :> {f[x_] = 2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: +5 if I am allowed!

Comment: You are allowed to show appreciation, easiest way is to click the up facing triangle, which gives reputation points.  And in this day and age, we all feed off imaginary internet points :-)

Comment: +1 legal contribution made. Dead right about feeding off imaginary internet points.....still better than "h index" for ghost authors

Answer (score 4):

A possible option

```
 Manipulate[a = 0; b = 10; dx = (b - a)/n; 
     f[x_] = 2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2; 
        Show[DiscretePlot[2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2, {x, 0, b, dx}, 
       ExtentSize -> Left, 
            PlotRange -> {{a, 10.5}, {0, 2600}}, 
       ColorFunction -> (Green & ), 
            ExtentElementFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], 
           Rectangle @@ Transpose[#1]} & )], 
          Plot[2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 3*x + 2, {x, a, b}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]], {n, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}]
```

Note: I have deleted the last code line

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but i really want is that I can put the sum of Riemman into the code, so that when I get more a bigger interval it will get a more accurate result to the integral value.

Comment: Sure, first answer is the best way then.